# Error trying to implement STL iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am fairly new to STL and iterators. I've used them quite frequently but am only now gaining an understanding of how they really work. For an assignment, I am tasked with re-writing a few STL iterators to understand what is going on under the hood. I'm midway through my `insert_iterator`:

```
template <class Container>
class m_insert_iterator : public std::iterator<output_iterator_tag, void, 
void, void, void>
{
protected:
    Container* container;
    typename Container::iterator it;

public:
    typedef Container container_type;

    // Constructor:
    m_insert_iterator(Container &x, typename Container::iterator i)
    {
        *container = x;
        it = i;
    }

    // Assignment operator:
    m_insert_iterator<Container> &operator=(const typename Container::value_type &value)
    {
        it = container->insert(this, value);
        ++it;
        return *this;
    }

    // No-ops:
    m_insert_iterator<Container> &operator*() { return *this };
    m_insert_iterator<Container> &operator++() { return *this };
    m_insert_iterator<Container> &operator++(int) { return *this };
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> v{ 2, 3, 4 };
    m_insert_iterator<vector<int>> ins_it(v, v.begin());
    ins_it = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
         cout << v[i] << " ";
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Whenever I call the constructor, my program crashes on `*container = x`. In the debugger I get an error message reading '0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.' Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in your understanding of pointers, you can't assign anything to an uninitialized pointer. so you can't assign a reference to an uninitialized pointer in your constructor:

```
*container = x;  // container is uninitialized, so this function will generate an AccessViolation
```

Instead you should use it as

```
container = std::addressof(x);
```

In this case you initialize your pointer with address of the reference that passed to you, but in your case you are trying to copy the reference to address that your pointer is pointing to it and since your pointer is not initialized, you are trying to write to an unknown location of the memory.

In best case you get an AccessDenied or something like that but you can also cause strange errors if it happen to write to a memory that is writable to your program. For example you may override value of one or more of your variables

Comment: Thanks! I realized I made that silly error as soon as I posted it, and I'm not getting that crash anymore. I've now got the member declaration as `Container* container = new Container;`, which works as far as I can tell. Now, when I call `operator=`, I am getting a crash stating 'Expression: vector insert iterator outside range'. Kind of confused by this as `m_insert_iterator.it` should be storing an iterator to the beginning of `v`, correct? (I've updated the question to include a test program.)

Comment: `new Container` creates, well, a new container, so that the copied iterator doesn't point into the container you're pointing at.  BigBoss said what to do: `container = std::addressof(x);`

Comment: Thank you both, its working. Looks like I need to go back a few steps and take a good look at pointers again.